# Formula to a conjunctive normal form

Tags: logic

I am stuck when converting a formula to a conjunctive normal form. I am at this point:

$\neg(P\vee\neg Q)\vee(\neg P\leftrightarrow Q)$

$(\neg P\wedge\neg(\neg Q))\vee(\neg(\neg(\neg P)\vee\neg Q)\vee\neg(\neg P\vee Q))$

$(\neg P\wedge Q)\vee(\neg (P\vee\neg Q)\vee(\neg(\neg P)\wedge\neg Q))$

$(\neg P\wedge Q)\vee(\neg P\wedge\neg(\neg Q))\vee(P\wedge\neg Q)$

$(\neg P\wedge Q)\vee(\neg P\wedge Q)\vee(P\wedge\neg Q)$

$(\neg P\wedge Q)\vee(P\wedge\neg Q)$

And from there I've tried different things. But I'm not sure if any of them is correct. Also, I developed it in a different way too:

$(\neg P\wedge Q)\vee((P\vee Q)\wedge(\neg P\vee\neg Q))$

Could you help me how to continue with it, please?

Comment: I believe this has already been answered

Comment: No, it was to a disjunctive normal form.

Comment: if you're more comfortable with disjunctive normal form (DNF), then you can (1) first negate the formula you're working with (2) put in DNF (3) negate again. Now it will be in conjunctive normal form.

Answer (score 1):

I shall take up from where it is left:

$(\neg P\wedge Q)\vee(P\wedge\neg Q)$

By distribution of $\vee$ over $\wedge$:

$((\neg P\wedge Q)\vee P)\wedge((\neg P\wedge Q)\vee\neg Q)$

By distribution of $\wedge$ over $\vee$:

$((\neg P\vee P)\wedge(Q\vee P))\wedge((\neg P\vee\neg Q)\wedge(Q\vee\neg Q))$

Replacing tautologies:

$(\top\wedge(Q∨P))\wedge((\neg P\vee\neg Q)\wedge\top)$

By the equivalence $\top\wedge p\leftrightarrow p$:

$(Q\vee P)\wedge(\neg P\vee\neg Q)$